# Form action affects only the form itself

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, action

I'm working on a single PHP file, which has 2 different forms.

Example:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="box1">
<input type="submit" value="submit1" name="submit">
</form>
<br>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="box2">
<input type="submit" value="submit2" name="submit">
</form>
```

My problem is, I want to make both of them work at the same time, independent from each other. For example, when I hit 'submit1', the whole index.php reloads since action is set to that page. The other checkbox might lose it's condition, if I set it to checked before submitting the first form. Might be confusing, I know.. Since I have PHP code behind, I can' really handle the whole thing between 1 form tag. That's why I'm asking if there's another option like javascript, or something. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not understanding why you cannot use one form for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a javascript cookie. You could set it so the cookie will have the fields and values of everything in both forms, and then is saved/created upon submit. Then once the page is reloaded, javascript can split the cookie and refill the field values for the other form. You might need a hidden field in both forms so that you can identify which form was submitted. Here's a tutorial that might explain cookies to you in greater detail: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm

Comment: I was just wondering if I could use cookies somehow in this case... But was not sure. :) Thank you!!